# Is it possible for Month names to be shown in my language

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display Months in my language, which is also Cyrillic. Here's my code.

```
<?php
    $timestamp = get_the_time( 'U' );
    $date = date( 'd-m', $timestamp );
    $today = date( 'd-m' );
    $yesterday = date( 'd-m', strtotime( 'yesterday' ) ); 

    if ( $date == $today ) {
        echo "Денес";//"today";
    } elseif ( $date == $yesterday ) {
        echo "Вчера";//"yesterday";
    } else {
        echo the_time('d-m H:i');//"Earlier"; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a combination of setlocale and strftime.

```php
<?php


$result = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sr'); //set locale to cyrillic

// handle your error here, if $result is false, it means the locale is not supported by your system


$month_name = strftime("%B");
```

You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/39cwe7zf(v=vs.90) for different languages you want to set.

Comment: forgot to mention in your case you will use setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sr');

Comment: It doesn't work. Please be more specific? Or implent your answer in my code.

Comment: Hi @LjubisaTrajkov, what error did you get? Btw, I couldn't tell where you want to output the month in your original question. In any case, I shall update the example.

Comment: I want to output the Month on the last line of code.

Comment: else echo the_time('d-m H:i');

Comment: ok, well please see the revised example, i was able to get something like 'avgust', if you get 'august' it means the locale is not supported. you can try other locale variations like sr_Cyrl_RS

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, but in my editor, it always outputs "August", i think it should ouputs "Avgust" or "Август" in cyrilc. My native language is Macedonian. You can try with 'mk'

Comment: in that case, it means most likely your system doesn't have the locale. you can run a `locale -a` on your terminal to see what all locales are installed, and you can check here to see how to add the locale you need https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IntlDateFormatter:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2019-08-25', new DateTimezone('Europe/Moscow'));

$fmt = datefmt_create(
    'ru_RU',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Europe/Moscow',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
);

datefmt_set_pattern($fmt, 'LLLL');

echo 'месяц: ' . datefmt_format($fmt, $dateTime);
```

Output: 
месяц: Август